# firebase Authentication Upgrade from FB 2 to 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase I'm exporting data and Auth Users from a 2.0 Firebase project to a new Firebase 3.0 project. This Firebase 3.0 project will be used for our test run, before we actually migrate the live dataset.

Know the export of the database worked fine, however I can't export the Auth Users in 2.0 using. The cli and firebase auth:export doesn't work with Firebase 2.0 projects.

I have already submitted a request with Firebase support to provide an xml with 2.0 Auth Users, however FB support denied this.

Anybody any ideas, how I can get an export of my Auth Users?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to export to go from 2.0 to current Firebase - just upgrade and your auth users are migrated. See the paragraph on auth in https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your response. I knew that and I had to phrase my question better, unfortunately my clients uses the FB 2 dataset as his live environment and he doesn't want to migrate without completing a test run.

So I'm actually trying the create a mirror of the FB 2 in a separate FB 3 project.

Comment: So you can migrate safely - the old SDKs will keep working. So what I'd likely do is upgrade, export the auth, import into a new project, and then test the new SDK against that one.